# Kafka Offsets out of range

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm writing a program in scala for spark streaming connection with kafka and I'm getting the following error:

```
18/02/19 12:31:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 39)
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {prensa4-0=744}
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:189)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/02/19 12:31:39 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 39, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {prensa4-0=744}
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:189)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1327)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply$mcZ$sp(RDD.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.isEmpty(RDD.scala:1461)
        at itcl.adquisicionDatos$$anonfun$main$3.apply(adquisicionDatos-gonvarri.scala:212)
        at itcl.adquisicionDatos$$anonfun$main$3.apply(adquisicionDatos-gonvarri.scala:200)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {prensa4-0=744}
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:189)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        ... 3 more
```

enable.auto.commit is True and auto.offset.reset is "latest".

Some time ago it was working fine, I tried to turn auto commit to false and use manual offset commit but I didn't manage to make it works so I return to this configurations but I'm also getting this error, so I figure it's not due to manual committing.

Some help about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue. For us the problem was:

1. master creates tasks like "read from that topic-partition form offset X 
   to offset Y" and passes that tasks to executors.
2. executor receives tasks and start consuming data form topic-partition. At that time, due to topic configuration (time or size retention) offset X become unavailable. KafkaConsumer that is created for consuming messages doesn't have offset reset policy.
3. result is exception you see

solution: you need to tune

- your kafka topic config
- speed of your spark job  (i.e. decrease batch time, increase number of executors).

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to tune your kafka topic config"?

Comment: @Hasangi you need to unsure that the data is stored in Kafka for long enough to be read by your spark job. So, you can increase time/size for storing your topic